# How to control the fields displayed on Contact merge

Tags: contact, standard-objects, merge, merge-field

I have an existing org, which is using a standard merge on Contact Object. My issue is that, while choosing the values which are to be reflected on the parent Contact, only 5 fields of the Contact object are displayed. The rest are read only.

I am trying to understand how to control the fields which are displayed.

This is for the second page where field values are to be chosen and not the first page, where the merged records are to be chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most fields are only displayed if they have a value in them (contact information such as emails and phones are always shown). Fields are made editable only if the user has Edit access to the field and there is a conflict. Non-conflicting values are read-only, and the value chosen will be whichever version has data in it. There's nothing to configure, because it is all rendered dynamically based on the available data. I couldn't find a Help Document that dove in any more detail, just what I've observed in Salesforce.

Comment: Yes, I searched in help docs as well, but there weren't any detailed explanation. Thank you so much for this. I did some experiments as well, and whatever you explained matches Salesforce function.